# Installation profile similar to openatrium but focusing on projects

Tags: distributions

I'm looking for an install profile (or Drupal based app) similar to [Open Atrium](http://openatrium.com/features), but focus on projects rather than on contacts and tasks; something that is similar to Basecamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an install profile, but there is a good module for that (6 only), called [Storm](http://drupal.org/project/storm).